# Resource object returned instead of Mongoose.count value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, meanjs

I'm having a little trouble trying to retrieve Mongoose.count values from a function in my back end API within my mean.js application. Everything is routed correctly as far as I can see, and seems to be working absolutely fine until I get to the front end angular code and try to retrieve the data from the API via a service and $resource.

Here's my back end API function to retrieve the count of listings in a particular category, where the category is passed in correctly as parameter.

```
exports.getListingCountForSpecificCategory = function(req, res, next, category) {
    Listing.count({
        category: category,
        quantityAvailable: { $gt: 0 },
        listingActive: true
    }, function(err, count){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(category + ': ' + count);
            res.jsonp(count);
        }
    });
};
```

This runs correctly and within the console.log()

```
console.log(category + ': ' + count);
```

The category count is returned correctly. So, everything working correctly!

Until I get to retrieving the count value with angular on the front end. Here's the function I've written:

```
$scope.listingsCount = function(category) {
    $scope.catCount = Listings.listingsCategoryCount.query({
        category: category.alias
    });

    $scope.catCount.$promise.then(function(count){
        category.listingCount = count;
    });
};
```

When this function is run and the category object is passed into it, instead of it retrieving the count value e.g. 14, it seems to retrieve a resource promise object instead, with the count value nowhere to be seen. I've looked over the code a few times and can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here's the service I'm using, just in case you need to see it.

```
listingsCategoryCount: $resource('listingscount/:category', {
    category: '@_category'
}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false
    }
}),
```

It's a mystery to me why the count value isn't being returned. I may be going about this incorrectly of course. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource:

> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server.

Change this: `res.jsonp(count);` to `res.jsonp({ count: count });` and it should work: you'll get a `Resource` object with property `count`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked! Suppose it makes a bit of sense too. A dull moment from me :). Thanks again